# How do I use react-redux 'useSelector' with an additional variable?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a redux (sub) state that consists of a large number of similar entries.

```
export type PartnerCalculatorStateShape = {
    m16_19:number;
    m20_24:number;
    m25_34:number;
    m35_44:number;
    m45_64:number;
    m65_plus:number;
    f16_19:number;
    f20_24:number;
    f25_34:number;
    f35_44:number;
    f45_64:number;
    f65_plus:number;

};
```

I am using the [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) so my reducer is of this form (note that Redux Toolkit uses immutable update logic, so I can assign modify the state directly)

```
type PartnerCalculatorPayload = {
  key:string;
  value:number;
}

    export const partnerCalculatorSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'PartnerCalculator',
      initialState,
      reducers: {
        partnerCalculatorValueReceived(state, action: PayloadAction<PartnerCalculatorPayload>) {
          state[action.payload.key] = action.payload.value;
        }
      }
    });
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to use `useSelector`. What I want to do is have a selector function in my Redux file, something like this

```
export const selectorFunction = (state,key) => state[key]
```

where `key` would be `m20_24`, for example.  Then I would use that selector function in my React component

```
const myVar = useSelector(selectorFunction)
```

But how do I pass in the key?

The [official hooks documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples) recommends using closure to pass additional variables

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const TodoListItem = props => {
  const todo = useSelector(state => state.todos[props.id])
  return <div>{todo.text}</div>
}
```

However. `useSelector` will be in my React component and I want to keep the selector function I pass to `useSelector` inside my redux file, so I can't see how to use closure.

I suppose I could just pass the entire state out from my selector function

```
const selectorFunction = state => state
```

and then treat it as an object in my React component and key into it there

```
const myState = useSelector(selectorFunction)
const myVar = myState["m20_24"]
```

but that seems kind of ugly.

If that's the way to go, would `myVar` update anytime any of the fields in my Redux state changed?  I'm a bit unclear as to how the [useSelector equality testing mechanism](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) works -- it says it uses 'strict equality', so if any part of my state object changed (that is, if the field 'm20_24' changed) then `myVar` would be updated?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass an anonymous selector to `useSelector`, and then call the actual selector inside of there:

```js
const value = useSelector(state => selectValueByKey(state, props.key));
```

Comment: Just wondering. Is it possible to use an HOF approach here? Something like `useSelector(selectorHOF(props.key));` and then `const selectorHOF = key => state => state.todos[key];`

Comment: Sure, that's legal syntax if you want to do that.  I personally prefer the approach I showed and find it more readable, but that's up to you.